# updating dns CNAME

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to update a bunch of dns cname entry, using azure-powershell.
I have no troubles getting the dns entry I need to update, but my problem starts when trying to update the cname (due to the fact there can be only one cname entry).

I went to [azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets), and found about [set-azdnsrecordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.dns/set-azdnsrecordset?view=azps-7.1.0), but I failed to find the correct parameter/syntax to update the CNAME

Here is what I tried.

```
$rs = Get-AzDnsRecordSet -name "test1" -RecordType CNAME -ZoneName "zone.io" -ResourceGroupName "dns"
$rs.Records[0].Records = "new-test-v1.com"
Set-AzDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs
```

With error on $rs.Records[0].Records = "new-test-v1.com":

```
The property 'Records' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

echo $rs

```
Id                : /subscriptions/[redacted]/resourceGroups/[redacted]/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnszones/[redacted].io/CNAME/test1
Name              : test1
ZoneName          : zone.io
ResourceGroupName : dns
Ttl               : 3600
Etag              : [redacted]
RecordType        : CNAME
TargetResourceId  :
Records           : {test-v1.com}
Metadata          :
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
```

PS : I did found a working solution. Deleting/recreating the records works fine enough. I also realise that if something goes wrong in the creation segment, I lose my record (setting failsafe would be a lot of additional work), So I keep it as a last ressort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the workaround to update CNAME records in Azure DNS

***To update CNAME we have to remove the existing alias and then have to add a new one***.
We have tried with below `cmdlt` and updated the CNAME:

***PowerShell Cmd:-***

```
$rs = Get-AzDnsRecordSet -name "rahul" -RecordType CNAME -ZoneName "zone.com" -ResourceGroupName "rgname"
Remove-AzDnsRecordConfig -RecordSet $rs -Cname $rs.Records.cname | Set-AzDnsRecordSet
$newcname = "new-test-v1.com"
Get-AzDnsRecordSet -name "rahul" -RecordType CNAME -ZoneName "myzone.com" -ResourceGroupName "rgname" | Add-AzDnsRecordConfig -Cname $newcname | Set-AzDnsRecordSet
```

***SAMPLE OUTPUT:-***
[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn... That was the answer I didn't want to get. As stated at the end of my message, I already found this solution, And I don't like the fact to delete (and commit) before recreating. Well If that's the only way to do it, I will do it this way... And of course, I aussume it will not be possible to not run the Set-AzDns between the deletion and recration, ensuring commit of the deletion only if if the recreation is a success...

Comment: I did notice your usage of remove-Config instead of my more violent usage of Remove-Set. This should alleviate part of my concerns.

Comment: Thank you , we can use this cmd as well
 `$rs = Get-AzDnsRecordSet -name "rahul" -RecordType CNAME -ZoneName "myzone.com" -ResourceGroupName "rgname"
$rs.Records[0].cname = "new-test-v1.com"
Set-AzDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs`

Answer (score 1):

Climbing on AjayKumarGhose-MT shoulders (mention of -Cname $rs.Records.cname) , I did found the solution
I needed to use

```
$rs.Records[0].cname = "new-test-v1.com"
```

instead of

```
$rs.Records[0].Records = "new-test-v1.com"
```

Full solution is then :

```
$rs = Get-AzDnsRecordSet -name "test1" -RecordType CNAME -ZoneName "zone.io" -ResourceGroupName "dns"
$rs.Records[0].Records = "new-test-v1.com"
Set-AzDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs
```